# How to find out what is affecting the elements on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently building a site. When I refresh the page (as seen below), the two boxes with the brown outline start out at what seems to be 100% width, but then they re-size after about 1-2 seconds, and there is a small gap on the right hand side.

[image: example]

I'm pretty sure this isn't happening via the CSS, as there is a delay and I've looked through it all myself and can't find anything.

I am using Google Chrome's Developer Tools - is there any way that I can view any related JavaScript being ran on refresh that may be affecting these elements?

Comment: check in network tab which JS is called freaquently.

Comment: Under the _Elements_ tab in Chrome Dev Tools find the element that is resizing right click and a context menu will appear. Select _Break On..._ >> _Subtree Modifications_. What frameworks, libraries and resources are you using to build your site?

Comment: It is built on a variation of Bootstrap & uses jQuery. Thanks for the info, will try this out now and see if it does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chrome extension to quickly turn off javascript. If the problem dissappears, you know that javascript is causing the problem. If the problem is still there, then it is a CSS issue (which I think is the case, but we can't solve that for you as you didn't provide the code).

here is a link to the javascript switcher extension: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje

Comment: It most definitely is not a CSS issue as I have checked, but thanks for your answer, this gets me half way towards the solution by identifying the cause, and will be helpful for others. I try to retain posting all of my code on here as I like to find out the solution myself (with guidance), plus it keeps the answer open for others - so the replies aren't specifically tailored to my piece of code. Thanks!